# for loop and two different vectors

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a problem with a loop I want to build in R.

I have a vector

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Now I want to do a loop which does the following computation:

```
b[1] = 5*a[1] + 10*a[2] + 15*a[3] + 20*a[4]

b[2] = 5*b[1] + 10*a[1] + 15*a[2] + 20*a[3]

b[3] = 5*b[2] + 10*b[1] + 15*a[1] + 20*a[2]
```

and so on. If possible, the solution shouldn't contain any "built-in functions" (e.g `sum`) because this is a simplification of my real problem and I want to understand how to build such "recursive" loops and how to implement two different vectors in a loop.

Comment: "and so on" - I think you need to elaborate the underlying logic of the indexing.

Comment: Im sorry. The computations should be stored in a empty vector b. So the first computation step is the first element in the vector b => b[1]. This element is then used in the second step marked as b[1] => b[2]

Comment: Matrices will probably be your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 1:4
N = 3
temp = a #OR maybe it is temp = a[1:4]
b = numeric(0)
for(i in 1:N){
    b = c(b, sum((5 * 1:length(temp)) * temp))
    temp = c(tail(b, 1), head(temp, -1))
}
b
#[1]  150  850 5805
```

Comment: Thanks this works, though i cant use the expression sum((5 * 1:length(temp)) * temp) because my real problem has arbitrary constants and not 5, 10, etc. I guess replacing it with just b = c(b, 5*temp[1]+10*temp[2]+15*temp[3]+20*temp[4]) is fine, at least it gives the right results. Thank you very much for your help and @Ken S. thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for how long this process should last, but I'll go ahead and stop it after 10 runs:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)

fct <- function(vect){
  return(5*vect[1] + 10*vect[2] + 15*vect[3] + 20*vect[4])
}

inds <- 1:4
for(i in 1:10){
  a <- c(a, fct(a[inds]))
  inds <- inds+1
}

b <- setdiff(a, c(1,2,3,4))
# [1] 1.500000e+02 3.100000e+03 6.430500e+04 1.334120e+06 2.767872e+07 5.742448e+08 1.191374e+10
# [8] 2.471719e+11 5.128026e+12 1.063901e+14
```

Comment: I have calculated the first 5 iterations manually and it seems that this code doesn't give the right results (unless i calculated wrong). I get b[1]=150, b[2]=850, b[3]=5805, b[4]=40020 and b[5]=274350